# Prestashop - one of my modul's is acting wired

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm using a supershop template. The modul - Vertical Mega Menus Modul
is disappearing and appearing again when i update a product. This doesnt make sense?

Website: [site](http://gooffice.dk/da)

Comment: What do you mean with "when i update a product". And have you tried contacting the template developer?

Comment: It dont do it anyome. Some times Prestashop is a real crap system